# UiTabBarController's tabs aren't showing at all but functional, what could be causing this issue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

As you can see in the image below the tab bar is visible but the tabs aren't. However I am still able to click where both of the tabs would be and flick between 2 views.

What could be wrong?

**AppDelegate Code:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    HypnosisViewController *hvc = [[HypnosisViewController alloc] init];

    TimeViewController *tvc = [[TimeViewController alloc] init];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:hvc, tvc, nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    [[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarController];



    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Regards

[image]

Comment: Read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS". There is a whole section on setting up tab controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared any titles or images for your TabBar items.
Use something like this: initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:

Comment: Oh, this is my first time working with UITabBarController. I thought there would atleast be an outline of the tabs like in the tutorial book I'm following but there isn't. I try and add some titles and see what happens.